# What is the return type of resolve and reject function of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, webstorm, es6-promise

I am trying to find the return type of resolve and reject function of a Promise I am creating with typescript, so that tslint does not complain based on the typedef rules.

Here is the code :

promises.ts

```
const promise: Promise<number> = new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    //the resolve / reject functions control the fate of the promise
    resolve(123);
});

//The promise fate can be subscribed to using .then (if resolved) or .catch (if rejected)
promise.then((res) => {
    console.log('I get called:', res === 123);      //I get called: true
});
```

---

tslint.json

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "eofline": false,
        "no-console": false,
        "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
        "comment-format": false,
        "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
        "quotemark": false,
        "typedef": [true, "call-signature", "arrow-call-signature", "parameter", "arrow-parameter", "property-declaration", "variable-declaration", "member-variable-declaration"],
        "typedef-whitespace": false,
        "whitespace": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */                       
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation:  */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./build/",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */        
    "strict": true,                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                      /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */                   
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */           
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */

    /* Source Map Options */                  
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */                
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "TypescriptProject5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Right now tslint complains about resolve, reject and res (expected arrow parameter to have a typedef)

Update #2 : This code does not give me any tslint or TS errors

```
const promise: Promise<number> = new Promise((resolve: (value?: {} | PromiseLike<{}> | undefined) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void): void => {
    //the resolve / reject functions control the fate of the promise
    resolve(123);
});

//The promise fate can be subscribed to using .then (if resolved) or .catch (if rejected)
promise.then((res: number) => {
    console.log('I get called:', res === 123);      //I get called: true
});
```

Comment: This is another forbidden action from tslint but I can disable this rule inside tslint.json

Comment: I've tried to use Function declaration but it is not working for res (second statement in the code)

Comment: Check Update#2.Of course I can always declare them as Function as you proposed.Which one do you believe is the best coding practice?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to describe the type of the parameters when the TypeScript compiler infers the type automatically.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the 2nd update?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always check the definitions inside the [lib.d.ts file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts), in this case the definition for the [PromiseConstructorLike](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1321) is:

```
declare type PromiseConstructorLike = new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) => PromiseLike<T>;
```

Which means that the type for resolve is:

```
(value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void
```

And for reject:

```
(reason?: any) => void
```

So both return `void`

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid answer but the type definition for resolve and res is not working.
I am getting several errors.

Comment: in other words use     "noImplicitAny": false,

Answer (score -9):

This is trivial to test.

```js
new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    console.log(res());
});

new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    console.log(rej());
});
```

They both return `undefined`.

Comment: If I define the resolve parameter as string I am getting an error that says that this variable should be value?:{} | PromiseLike<{}> | undefined.
I don't know if that helps.